# Rounding TimeDate value

Tags: sql-server

I need help to round the StartTime and EndTime of a class to 15:00:00 instead of 15:00:00.0000000.

Below is a screenshot of the results from my query:

[image]

Below is my SELECT query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Module.ModuleCode,ClassType.ClassTypeName,Convert(time,Class.StartTime) AS StartTime , Convert(time,Class.EndTime)AS EndTime, Building.BuildingName,RoomCode.RoomCode
FROM Class INNER JOIN Module ON Class.ModuleId = Module.ModuleId 

INNER JOIN RoomCode ON Class.RoomCodeId = RoomCode.RoomcodeId 
INNER JOIN Building ON RoomCode.BuildingId = Building.BuildingId 
INNER JOIN Days ON Class.DayId = Days.DayID 
INNER JOIN ClassType ON Class.ClassTypeId = ClassType.ClassTypeId WHERE Module.ModuleId =  6
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for display in SSMS, you could convert to `time(0)` instead of `time` which is defaulting to `time(7)`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Module.ModuleCode,ClassType.ClassTypeName,Convert(time(0),Class.StartTime) AS StartTime , Convert(time(0),Class.EndTime)AS Endtime, Building.BuildingName,RoomCode.RoomCode
FROM Class INNER JOIN Module ON Class.ModuleId = Module.ModuleId 

INNER JOIN RoomCode ON Class.RoomCodeId = RoomCode.RoomcodeId 
INNER JOIN Building ON RoomCode.BuildingId = Building.BuildingId 
INNER JOIN Days ON Class.DayId = Days.DayID 
INNER JOIN ClassType ON Class.ClassTypeId = ClassType.ClassTypeId WHERE Module.ModuleId =  6
```

Comment: I want to display the StartDate & EndDate in separate columns as 08/03/2017 instead of  08/03/2017 00:00:000. How do you do this?

Comment: @DavidCraven You can convert to `date` for ISO format e.g. `convert(date,StartDate)`, or if you want a specific convert style, `convert(char(10),StartDate,101)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql